# Using array_filter to filter multidimensional array with another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, the second is multidimensional. I'm trying to return a third array where the service_id in Array2 match the values in Array1.

```
Array1
(
    [0] => 158
    [1] => 162
)

Array2
(
    [localhost] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [host_name] => localhost                        
                    [current_state] => 0                   
                    [service_id] => 158
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [host_name] => localhost
                    [current_state] => 0                        
                    [service_id] => 159
                )
        )
    [192.168.0.43] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [host_name] => 192.168.0.43                        
                    [current_state] => 0
                    [service_id] => 168
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [host_name] => 192.168.0.43
                    [current_state] => 1
                    [service_id] => 162
                )
        )
)
```

So Array3 should be:

```
Array3
(
    [localhost] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [host_name] => localhost                        
                    [current_state] => 0                   
                    [service_id] => 158
                )

     [192.168.0.43] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [host_name] => 192.168.0.43
                    [current_state] => 0                   
                    [service_id] => 162
                )
        )
)
```

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't appear to be filtering the entire array.

```
$Array3= array_filter($Array2, function ($value) use ($Array1) {
        return in_array(array_shift($value)['service_id'], $Array1);
});
```

Am I close here, What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you want to filer at a second depth that it needs to loop across the first level and then filter the second level (think that sort of makes sense).

So this code uses `array_map()` to loop over the host level of the array (`localhost` and `192.168.0.43`) and then uses `array_filter()` within this.  Have to use `use()` to pass the lookup array into each level of the function

```
$array3 = array_map(function($data) use ($Array1)
    { return array_filter($data, function($sub) use ($Array1)
        { return in_array($sub["service_id"], $Array1); });
}, $Array2);

print_r($array3);
```

prints...

```
Array
(
    [localhost] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [host_name] => localhost
                    [current_state] => 0
                    [service_id] => 158
                )

        )

    [192.168.0.43] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [host_name] => 192.168.0.43
                    [current_state] => 1
                    [service_id] => 162
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

So below should be what you need to achieve $Array3 :

```
$Array3 = array(array($Array2[0][0], $Array2[0][1], $Array1[0]), array($Array2[1][0],
$Array2[1][1], $Array1[1]));
```

However to achieve this more dynamically, you'd want to use something like :

```
$Array3 = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $Array2[0].length; $i++){

array_push($Array3, array($Array2[$i][0], $Array2[$i][1], $Array1[$i]));

}

var_dump($Array3) // For debug only.
```